# Admob Ad ID into variables on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Can I put the Admob Ad ID into variables on Android? I want to make this app that when I input the adunit ID in my app. It will change the adunit to whatever ad ID that I input.

Thank you.

Comment: The adunit ID is going to be introduced by hand in an inputtext in the app? Or sent via web to the device?

Comment: you might want to try Admob ad meditation for picking up your ad network and ad id's dynamically - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-custom-events

Comment: It will be input by the user then the ad in that app is theirs.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I'm using appybuilder, so hard coding is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Although I have not tested, but it will work. Use below code

```
mAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: This will only work when you mAdView Programatically else it will throw error

Comment: I think that will work but, I forgot to mention. I'm using appybuilder, so hard coding is not possible?